telemetry data collection using Sunbird Obsrv
I want to implement Sunbird Obsrv to collect telemetry data including user generated events. I have done setup of Kafka, zookeeper, postgres, redis and druid but unable to understand about implementation to collect telemetry data from an application using Sunbird Obsrv. Is this implementation require extensive code changes to our application or without code change we can start collecting telemetry data and how?
Can anybody provide help with this. I appreciate any assistance you can provide.
I have gone through its document https://obsrv.sunbird.org/ but i could not understand the process to get started. I am not in a position to make extensive code changes in our node.js application to implement this.
I have done server setup through steps as mentioned in https://obsrv.sunbird.org/guides/installation/aws-installation-guide
I have explored APIs for Datasets, Datasources, Ingest from https://github.com/Sunbird-Obsrv/obsrv-api-service
